# Changing text on a button multiple times and moving a div with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I currently have a box-shaped div (id = "container") that is located at the center of the page. Inside that div I have a button that says "clickMe". What I want is that when I click that button, the div moves to the left side of the screen and the text on the button text changes to "Collapse", and when I click it again (collapse button) the div returns back to the center of the screen and the button text changes to "Extend".

For that I have the following three files:

```
index.php
menu.php
move.js
```

**menu.php**

```
//...........................
<button id="mover" type="button" >ClickMe</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move.js"></script>
//........................
```

**move.js**

```
var collapsed = true; //flag

//jQuery button listener
$("#mover").click(function() {


  if (collapsed) {

    console.log("phase1");

    //Moves div to the left of the page
    $("#container").animate({
      right: '25%'
    }, "slow");

    //Change the text on the button to "Collapse" (doesn't work)
    document.getElementById("mover").innnerHTML = "Collapse";
    collapsed = false;
  } else {

    console.log("phase2");

    //Returns the div to the center of the page
    $("#container").animate({
      left: '0%'
    }, "slow");

    //Change the text on the button to "Extend" (doesn't work)
    document.getElementById("mover").innnerHTML = "Extend";
    collapsed = true;

  }
});
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="bottom">
    <?php include ("menu.php"); ?>          
</div>
```

What happens is that when the button is clicked once, the div moves to the left and then to the center. The text on the button is still "ClickMe" (doesn't change) and the div won't move at all if I clicked the button once more.

This is what prints on the console when I click the button the first time:

```
VM1608 move.js:7                phase1
VM1612 move.js:14               phase2
VM1616 move.js:7                phase1
VM1620 move.js:14               phase2
VM1624 move.js:7                phase1
VM1628 move.js:14               phase2
move.js:7                       phase1
```

(when I click the button again it prints the same 9 outputs but the div won't move)

Just to recap I have got 3 issues with my code: changing the text on the button, move the div to the left when the button is clicked and to the center when it is clicked again and I want to be able to do this more than once.
PS: I tried to use delay in the first if statement but I got the same result.

Comment: Why are you animating the `right` property in phase 1 and then the `left` property in phase 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem doing what you seem to be trying to do.

This also makes use of the `complete` callback in [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to change the button text.

```js
var collapsed = false;

$('#mover').on('click', function() {

  if (collapsed) {

    $("#move-me").animate({
      left: 0
    }, "slow", function() {
    
     $('#mover').html('Original text');
    });

    collapsed = false;

  } else {

    $("#move-me").animate({
      left: '25%'
    }, "slow", function() {
    
     $('#mover').html('Changed text');
    });

    collapsed = true;
  }
});
```

```css
#move-me {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="mover">
  Original text
</button>

<div id="move-me">

</div>
```